# Passing category id in selectbox (ajax request)

Tags: octobercms

I have this query to display categories a user posted in and it works fine

```
$this['items'] = Advert::select('cat_id')
                   ->distinct('cat_id')
                   ->with('cats')
                   ->where('user_id', $slug)
                  ->get();
```

twig

```
 <select name="product" class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"  data-request="onUserPro" data-request-update="pro: '#myDiv'">
    <option selected>Category List</option>
        {% for key, item in items %}
        <option value={{ key }}> {{ item.cats.cat_title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}

  </select>
```

Now i want to display the products via ajax belonging to this each category when clicked and then updating the partial with

```
function onUserPro()
{
$slug  =  $this->param('slug');
$id = post('product');


$this['allproducts'] = Advert
::whereHas('cats', function ($query) use ($id) {
                  $query->where('id','=',$id); //it only works when i change this to an id like ..where('id', 7)
               })
->where('user_id',$slug)->orderby('created_at','desc')->get();


}
```

I don't think i am passing the id the way i should or something else is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Got it by changing

```
 {% for key, item in items %}
        <option value={{ key }}> {{ item.cats.cat_title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
```

to

```
 {% for item in items %}
        <option value={{ item.cats.id }}> {{ item.cats.cat_title }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
```